# Android requestWait of usb serial is not blocking for FT232R device

Tags: android, usbserial, usb-otg

I am currently using:
Device Name: FT232R device.
Device Serial Number: A104WOUG.
Device Description: FT232R USB UART.
Device ID: 04036001.
Device Location: 41d1.

for an Android device configured with OTG-USBS. Everything works fine.
Recently, I observed that when the cable is long connected with the Android device,
it drains the battery of Android.

After an investigation, I found that the blocking function
requestWait() in  android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection
is not blocking (I have tested with other brand, i.e. Prolific, it is blocking function).

I would like to know which parameters should I need to set in order to let the function requestWait a blocking function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By default ftdi devices periodically (each 16msec) send 2 status bytes containing the values of control lines. You could try increasing the latency timer with their FT_SetLatencyTimer() function